# What is the best way to combine old and new Investment 401k?

Tags: united-states, 401k, rollover

I just changed my job few months ago and my old employer sent me my 401k Details with details of the person or the company who manages 401k for their employees.

Now, I want to merge this account with my current 401k Account and I do not know what is the best way to to this. I searched online and mostly when it comes to rolling over a 401k account, its mostly rolling it over to IRA account. I did not find a lot of help on how to merge it with my new 401k account.

I considered a few options:

- Contact the person that is listed on my old 401k Account
- Contact the person in my new company who handles the 401k and everything in my new company
- If there is an online service like fidelity or Vanguard who can do it for a fee, I can go for that

But I wanted to know what could be the easiest to approach?

Comment: Why would you prefer to roll it over to another 401(K), instead of to an IRA? You'll generally get more and better investment choices in an IRA instead of a 401(K).

Comment: Do not attempt to do this on your own. Above all else do not let anyone send you a check during the transfer. It could create a taxable event instead of a qualified rollover and you do NOT want that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ability to move money from an old 401K to a current 401K is based completely on the rules of the new company. If they don't allow you to transfer funds into the plan you are out of luck. You can ask them to consider it in the future, but they don't have to allow this.

Unless the funds in question are being run by Fidelity or Vanguard they have nothing to do with the 401K-to-401K transfer.

If you company does allow it, they will have all the forms and procedures.